# Save ffprobe Output to Log File?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, ffprobe

I made a script for ffprobe I can use to view information of my media more easily.  An additional feature I want is to breakout the output information to a log file.

Implementation 1:

```
@echo off

for %%f in (%*) do (ffprobe -hide_banner -i %%f>"%~dp1ffprobe.log)
```

Implementation 2:

```
@echo off

(
for %%f in (%*) do (ffprobe -hide_banner -i %%f)
)>"%~dp1ffprobe.log"
```

The issue I am having is that the log is being created in the expected location but it it always empty with either of these implementations. Usually either of these methods for breaking into a file have worked for me. Is there a native or alternative way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

With ffprobe 5.1 or later, you can add `-o OUTFILE` to store probe data in a file.

If using redirection with earlier versions, redirect stderr as well.